# Is there a way to save chunks of an array in a new array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

`["Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5", "Element6"]`

that i loop through and save equal size chunks of in new arrays:

`["Element1", "Element2"], ["Element3", "Element4"], ["Element5", "Element6"]`

For each iteration of this process I want to save the non-sliced portion of the initial array in a new array so that each iteration of the process gives me two arrays:

The chunk:

`["Element3", "Element4"]`

And the "rest" of the initial array:

`["Element1", "Element2", "Element5", "Element6"]`

At the moment i can fetch the chunks while looping through the initial array with this:

```
for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
   temparray = group_array.slice(i, i + chunk);
}
```

But i have no way of fetching the remainder of the array through each iteration, is there any way of doing this in JavaScript?

Comment: After slicing, `group_array` is your remainder array.

Comment: @Ava, that is not true. `group_array` is not affected by `slice`.

Comment: @Ava: Only if he used [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: @Ava I don't want to ```splice()```the array since i want to keep the original data in the array for the next iteration.

Comment: @VLAZ Right, but that only gives me the remainder of any chunks **bold** behind the current chunk, not any chunks that might be in front of it in the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to write it as easy to understand as I could :3

First you are getting starting and ending index of the chunk. For loop increases its index by two because you want your chunk to be 2 elements length.
Then you slice the chunk. Next you are getting two resting parts of the array. First starts at index 0 and ends on chunk start. And second part starts on the chunk end and ends on the last array element.

```js
const arr = [
  'Element1',
  'Element2',
  'Element3',
  'Element4',
  'Element5',
  'Element6',
];

function customSlice(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    const startIdx = i;
    const endIdx = i + 2;

    const chunk = arr.slice(startIdx, endIdx);
    console.log('chunk -> ', chunk);

    const rest1 = arr.slice(0, startIdx);
    const rest2 = arr.slice(endIdx, arr.length);
    const rest = rest1.concat(rest2);
    console.log('rest -> ', rest);
  }
}

customSlice(arr);
```

Comment: Yeah, just added it.

Answer (score 0):

So You can use Javascript splice(i, n) function that removes array content from index i to i+n. This method is called from array itself and changes that array, so you will need to copy initial Array and than make operation on this arr

```
const startArr = ["Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5", "Element6"];
let tmpSubArr;
let tmpWithoutSlicedArr;
let chunk = 1;
for (i = 0, j = startArr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
   tmpWithoutSliceArr = [...startArr]; // This copies starting array and then removing unwanted content
   tmpWithoutSliceArr.splice(i, chunk + 1);
   tmpSubArr = startArr.slice(i, i + chunk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all elements that are outside the index range range for the current chunk. If the current range is, for example, `2` to `5`, then you want everything where the index is outside that. This is easily doable using the second parameter of the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback:

```js
const group_array = ["Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5", "Element6"];

const chunk = 2;

for (let i = 0, j = group_array.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
  const chunkStart = i;
  const chunkEnd = i + chunk;
  
  //get chunk
  const temparray = group_array.slice(i, i + chunk);
  
  //get everything where the index is ouside the chunk index range
  const restArray = group_array
    .filter((_, index) => index < chunkStart || index >= chunkEnd);
  
  
  console.log("tempArray", temparray);
  console.log("restArray", restArray);
}
```